# ACF and PACF interpretation

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have difficulty reading the ACF and PACF plots and determining the lag for the model.

I am forecasting the  daily electricity load data which looks as follows:

```
           date  temperature   load   weekday month weekend day
1    2010-01-01         -28 256131       5    01       0   1
2    2010-01-02         -24 277749       6    01       1   2
3    2010-01-03         -53 264166       0    01       1   3
4    2010-01-04         -42 319847       1    01       0   4
5    2010-01-05         -17 321376       2    01       0   5
```

To get the ACF and PACF I have performed the following:

```
#create time series     
NLdailyts <- ts(NLdaily$load, frequency =365.25, start = c(2010,1,1))
#difference time series 
NLdailytsdiff <- diff(NLdailyts,differences = 365.25)

#ACF plot in days 
## Calculate, but not plot, acf
acfpl<- acf(NLdailytsdiff, plot = FALSE)
## Transform the lags from years to days 
acfpl$lag <- acfpl$lag * 365.25
## Plot the acf 
plot(acfpl, xlab="Lag (days)")

#PACF plot in days 
## Calculate, but not plot, acf
pacfpl<- pacf(NLdailytsdiff, plot = FALSE)
## Transform the lags from years to days 
pacfpl$lag <- pacfpl$lag * 365
## Plot the acf 
plot(pacfpl, xlab="Lag (days)")
```

Which gives me the following plots:

[ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdGQT.png) and [PACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbzYu.png)

EDIT: I have found out that alternating positive and negative values mean that the data is stationary.

How should I interpret both? And which lag should I use?

Comment: What is the purpose of fitting this model? If you're trying to forecast just use auto.arima from the forecast package. I have some code below but can go into more detail if needed. ARIMA will use differencing to make the data stationary and will automatically select how many lags to use.

Comment: Also, alternating positive and negative values does not mean that it is stationary. What you really want is none of the residuals of a fit to show up as significant and no pattern to be shown in the PACF or ACF. However, this can actually be somewhat difficult to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think we need to establish the differences between ACF and PACF. They are both showing if there is significant correlation between a point and lagged points. The difference is that PACF takes into consideration the correlation between each of the intermediate lagged points.

Looking at ACF could be misleading with what points are significant. For example, if y_(t-1) is strongly correlated this correlation could show up at y_(t-2), y_(t-3), etc.

[You can read this for more info.](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm)

Looking at your PACF plot it looks like you'd want to use AR(8). However, you also have weekly data so you might want to set weekly seasonality instead of yearly seasonality.

You could do something like this

```
library(forecast)
NLdailyts <- ts(NLdaily$load, frequency = 7, start = c(2010,1,1))
fit = auto.arima(NLdailyts)
```

That should determine the number of AR terms to use automatically.